# What if my lambda job, which is subscribed to an AWS SNS topic, goes down or stops working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have one publisher and one subscriber for my SNS topic in AWS.
Suppose my subscriber is getting failed and exiting with a failure.

Will SNS repush those failed messages?

**If not...**

Is there another way to achieve that goal where my system starts processing from the last successful lambda execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a retry policy, but if your application already received the message, then no. If something goes wrong you won't see it again and since Lambdas don't carry state...You could be in trouble.

I might consider looking at SQS instead of SNS. Remember, messages in SQS won't be removed until you remove them and you can set a window of invisibility. Therefore, you can easily ensure the next Lambda execution picks up where things left off (depending on your settings). Each Lambda would then be responsible for removing that message from SQS and that's how you'd know the message was processed.

Without knowing more about your application and needs, I couldn't say for sure...But I would take a look at it. I've built a "taskmaster" Lambda before that ran on a schedule and read from an SQS queue (multiple queues actually - the scheduled job passed different JSON event based on which queue to read from). It would then pass the job off to the appropriate Lambda "worker" which would then remove that message. Should it stop working...Well, the invisibility period would timeout (and 5 minutes isn't bad here given that's all Lambdas can execute for) and the next Lambda would pick it up. The taskmaster then would run as often as needed and read as many jobs from the queue as necessary. This really helps you have complete control over at what rate you are processing things, how many times you are retrying things, etc. Then you can also make use of a dead-letter queue to catch anything that may have failed (also, think about sticking things back into the queue).

You have a LOT of flexibility with SQS that I'm not really sure you get with SNS to be honest. I was never fond of SNS, though it too has a place and time and so again without knowing more here I couldn't say if SQS would be the fit for you...But I think your concerns can be taken care of with SQS if it makes sense for your application.